# Display subdomain instead of file path

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My problem is as follows:

I have a domain (`domain.com`) and a folder called page (`domain.com/page`).

The page folder contains a bunch of files including css files and an `index.html`.

My `.htaccess` file is in the root folder (`domain.com/.htaccess`) and includes this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This code removes the `www` part from the domain (displays as `domain.com` instead of `www.domain.com`).

I am looking to set up a subdomain, so that instead of displaying the url as `http://domain.com/page` it is displayed as `http://page.domain.com`

I've tried using this code below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^page\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page/
RewriteRule (.*) /page/$1
```

but visiting `page.domain.com` doesn't return anything, and going to `domain.com/page` still displays as `domain.com/page`.

My knowledge of `.htaccess` isn't the greatest so please don't go too advanced without explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(page\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+page/([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ http://page.domain.com/%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^page\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /page/$1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I'm getting a 500 internal server error. I've replaced the code (changing the dummy domain and page) in the .htaccess file in the root folder of the webspace (domain.com/).